# String length changes when read from text file (C)

Tags: c, text-files, string-length

my problem looks like this: 
I make a char array, lets say its length is A, then i write this array to file, then read it from the same file and its length is not A anymore, its bigger..
Source code:

```
char encrypted1[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqwxyz";
int encrypted1_len;
char *encrypted;
int encrypted_len;
encrypted1_len = strlen((char*)encrypted1);

f_cypher = fopen(CYPHER_FILE, "w");
fprintf(f_cypher, "%s", encrypted1);
fclose(f_cypher);

stat(CYPHER_FILE, &st);
size = st.st_size;
encrypted = malloc(size * sizeof *encrypted);
f_cypher = fopen(CYPHER_FILE, "r");
len = fread(encrypted, 1, size, f_cypher);
encrypted1[len] = '\0';
fclose(f_cypher);

encrypted_len = strlen((char*) encrypted);
printf("%s", encrypted);
```

In this example the lengths are 27 and then 40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allocating enough space for the string you read back. Your encrypted1 has 26 characters and one \0  string end marker, which makes 27. Now you write those 26 bytes to the file (do a ls -l - check the 26), allocate 26 bytes, and set encrypted1[len] to '\0', which is memory that you haven't allocated. Anything weird can happen from now on. Change `size` in malloc to `(size+1)` and look what happens.

Comment: hmm, but size=st.st_size already returns me 27, so if i allocate size+1 i will have 28 bytes

Comment: Ahhh.. this is because you have ...uvQwx... an extra character in your alphabet. So it's 27 bytes you read back, and you need 28 bytes to hold them including the 0 byte.

Comment: Okay i got the point, but the problem didnt go away, when i get my string back from file it looks like this: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqwxyzÍýýýý«««««««« and its length is 40

Comment: Aaahhh .. look at this: `len = fread(encrypted, 1, size, f_cypher);
encrypted1[len] = '\0';` .. you're putting the \0 at the end of the orignal string (encrypted1), not at the string you're reading back (encrypted). So encrypted has no terminator until, in a random memory location, there happens to be a \0 byte. Your code is full of surprises, as my Aaahhhs clearly indicate :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that C strings are supposed to be [null terminated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), but you're not writing the null character at the end.

One solution is to add the null character when you write it to the file (which makes it unnecessary to write the size explicitly):

```
encrypted1_len = strlen(encrypted1) + 1;
```

Or you can add the null character when you read it back from the file:

```
encrypted = malloc(size * sizeof *encrypted + 1);
encrypted[size] = '\0';
```

Comment: You probably havent noticed but i do null terminate it when reading from file (although i was not allocating space for null character) but still, the problem is that i dont get where those 13 characters come from..

Comment: @IgnasKizelevicius those 13 characters come from the area of memory in `encrypted` just after your string which you are reading accidentally. The line `encrypted = malloc(size * sizeof *encrypted);` looks strange to me. What is that supposed to be doing? It looks like you are allocating more space than you need and the null terminator is placed at the end of the allocated memory rather than the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this my friend:

```
char encrypted[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqwxyz"; /*27 characters */
f_cypher = fopen(CYPHER_FILE, "w");
fprintf(f_cypher, "%s", encrypted); /* could use fputs() instead */
fclose(f_cypher);

int source_length = sizeof(encrypted); /* could use strlen(encrypted) instead */
char buffer[source_length+1];  /* extra character for null terminator */
f_cypher = fopen(CYPHER_FILE, "r");
int len = fread(buffer, 1, source_length, f_cypher);
buffer[len] = '\0';
printf("%s\n",buffer);

printf("encrypted is %u characters long.\n", strlen(encrypted));
printf("buffer is %u characters long.\n", strlen(buffer));
```

Using `encrypted` and `encrypted1` for writing and reading is bound to cause confusions so I've changed destination variable to `buffer`.